# ORA-12728: invalid range in regular expression Inserts

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sql-insert

The error arises with the insert of the table clients and only in my computer, since testing with others if it manages to load it. Use sqldeveloper 18.2 and oracle database express edition 11g.

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE Clientes(
DNI_CIF VARCHAR2(9) NOT NULL CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(DNI_CIF, '[A-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z]')),
Contrasena VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
Telefono NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR2(25) UNIQUE,
TipoCliente VARCHAR2(25),
Nombre VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
FormaPago VARCHAR2(20),
NumeroCuenta VARCHAR2 (24),
CancelacionesIndebidas INT CHECK (CancelacionesIndebidas BETWEEN 0 and 3),
PRIMARY KEY(DNI_CIF),
CONSTRAINT Clientes_chk1 CHECK (TipoCliente IN ('Particular', 'Empresa', 'Administracion Publica'))
);
```

Procedure:

```
PROCEDURE insert_clientes(w_DNI_CIF clientes.dni_cif%TYPE,w_Contrasena clientes.contrasena%TYPE,w_Telefono clientes.telefono%TYPE,w_Email clientes.email%TYPE,
    w_TipoCliente clientes.tipocliente%TYPE,w_Nombre clientes.nombre%TYPE,
    w_FormaPago clientes.formapago%TYPE,w_NumeroCuenta clientes.numerocuenta%TYPE,
    w_CancelacionesIndebidas clientes.cancelacionesindebidas%TYPE);
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY INSERTS AS 


PROCEDURE insert_clientes(w_DNI_CIF clientes.dni_cif%TYPE,w_Contrasena clientes.contrasena%TYPE,w_Telefono clientes.telefono%TYPE,w_Email clientes.email%TYPE,
w_TipoCliente clientes.tipocliente%TYPE,w_Nombre clientes.nombre%TYPE,w_FormaPago clientes.formapago%TYPE,w_NumeroCuenta clientes.numerocuenta%TYPE,
w_CancelacionesIndebidas clientes.cancelacionesindebidas%TYPE)
IS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO Clientes (DNI_CIF,Contrasena,Telefono,Email,TipoCliente,Nombre,FormaPago,NumeroCuenta,CancelacionesIndebidas)
VALUES(w_DNI_CIF,w_Contrasena,w_Telefono,w_Email,w_TipoCliente,w_Nombre,w_FormaPago,w_NumeroCuenta,w_CancelacionesIndebidas);

END insert_clientes;
```

**Insert:**

```
INSERTS.insert_clientes('12312389P','12345678',666666666,'una@muno.com','Particular','Miguel de Unamuno','Transferencia','ES7119225879874039280971',0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap `insert_clientes` procedure in the package specification part of the package with `CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE INSERTS AS` in the beginning and `END INSERTS;` in the end. `END INSERTS;` is also missing for the package body.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE INSERTS AS
  PROCEDURE insert_clientes(w_DNI_CIF                clientes.dni_cif%TYPE,
                            w_Contrasena             clientes.contrasena%TYPE,
                            w_Telefono               clientes.telefono%TYPE,
                            w_Email                  clientes.email%TYPE,
                            w_TipoCliente            clientes.tipocliente%TYPE,
                            w_Nombre                 clientes.nombre%TYPE,
                            w_FormaPago              clientes.formapago%TYPE,
                            w_NumeroCuenta           clientes.numerocuenta%TYPE,
                            w_CancelacionesIndebidas clientes.cancelacionesindebidas%TYPE);
END INSERTS;
/
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY INSERTS AS
  PROCEDURE insert_clientes(w_DNI_CIF                clientes.dni_cif%TYPE,
                            w_Contrasena             clientes.contrasena%TYPE,
                            w_Telefono               clientes.telefono%TYPE,
                            w_Email                  clientes.email%TYPE,
                            w_TipoCliente            clientes.tipocliente%TYPE,
                            w_Nombre                 clientes.nombre%TYPE,
                            w_FormaPago              clientes.formapago%TYPE,
                            w_NumeroCuenta           clientes.numerocuenta%TYPE,
                            w_CancelacionesIndebidas clientes.cancelacionesindebidas%TYPE) IS

  BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Clientes
      (DNI_CIF,
       Contrasena,
       Telefono,
       Email,
       TipoCliente,
       Nombre,
       FormaPago,
       NumeroCuenta,
       CancelacionesIndebidas)
    VALUES
      (w_DNI_CIF,
       w_Contrasena,
       w_Telefono,
       w_Email,
       w_TipoCliente,
       w_Nombre,
       w_FormaPago,
       w_NumeroCuenta,
       w_CancelacionesIndebidas);

  END insert_clientes;
END inserts;
/
```

And execute as the following (So, there's no problem with the string you provided for `w_dni_cif` column):

```
SQL> exec inserts.insert_clientes('12312389P','12345678',666666666,'una@muno.com','Particular','Miguel de Unamuno','Transferencia','ES7119225879874039280971',0);
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> commit;

Commit complete
```